# Find 2 or more occurences of a pattern "submit report" or "submitted report" using vba regex

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I am new to vba regex and I need to find the fields in a very large report where the text in a text field or text cell contains 3 or more occurrences of the following pattern:

"submit report" or "submitted report" or "submitting rep" or "resubmitted rep" or  "resubmitting report" using vba regex, case insensitive.

I have not been able to figure out the regex and the condition count so it could be adjusted to 2, 3 or more.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to achieve this with RegEx and the following is surely not the best way to tackle the problem. But it certainly does the trick. Hope this helps:

```
Option Compare Text

Public Sub SearchForMultipleOccurencesOfReport()
Dim bolFoundSomehing As Boolean
Dim strLargeReport As String
Dim lngCounter As Long
Dim lngLooper As Long
Dim z As Variant

intCounter = 0
strLargeReport = "This is the text of your large report containing all these searched terms like submit report, submitting rep, or resubmitting report."

For lngLooper = 1 To 100000
    bolFoundSomehing = False
    z = InStr(1, strLargeReport, "submit report")
    If IsNumeric(z) And z > 0 Then
        lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
        bolFoundSomehing = True
        strLargeReport = Mid(strLargeReport, InStr(1, strLargeReport, "submit report") + Len("submit report"))
    End If
    z = InStr(1, strLargeReport, "submitted report")
    If IsNumeric(z) And z > 0 Then
        lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
        bolFoundSomehing = True
        strLargeReport = Mid(strLargeReport, InStr(1, strLargeReport, "submitted report") + Len("submitted report"))
    End If
    z = InStr(1, strLargeReport, "submitting rep")
    If IsNumeric(z) And z > 0 Then
        lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
        bolFoundSomehing = True
        strLargeReport = Mid(strLargeReport, InStr(1, strLargeReport, "submitting rep") + Len("submitting rep"))
    End If
    z = InStr(1, strLargeReport, "resubmitted rep")
    If IsNumeric(z) And z > 0 Then
        lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
        bolFoundSomehing = True
        strLargeReport = Mid(strLargeReport, InStr(1, strLargeReport, "resubmitted rep") + Len("resubmitted rep"))
    End If
    z = InStr(1, strLargeReport, "resubmitting report")
    If IsNumeric(z) And z > 0 Then
        lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
        bolFoundSomehing = True
        strLargeReport = Mid(strLargeReport, InStr(1, strLargeReport, "resubmitting report") + Len("resubmitting report"))
    End If
    If bolFoundSomehing = False Then Exit For
Next lngLooper

MsgBox "Found " & lngCounter & " occurences of the searched terms in the report."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with VBA at all, or the specifics of how VBA does RegEx, but this RegEx should match all of the terms you mentioned in your question:

```
/(?:re)?submit(?:ted|ting)? rep(?:ort)?/i
```

This will match **one** instance of any of the strings you mentioned. You could use RegEx subroutines or recursion to match multiple instances of this pattern, but I don't know wether VBA supports these. Here's an ugly but functional solution:

```
/(?:re)?submit(?:ted|ting)? rep(?:ort)?.+?(?:re)?submit(?:ted|ting)? rep(?:ort)?/i
```

This is just the same RegEx above repeated twice, with a `.+?` between them. This will cause the RegEx to match any and all characters between the first and second instances of the phrase you're looking for. If there's a match, it means that there are **at least** two instances of that phrase in the text.